# Task Scheduler Opens Excel file but keeps running and does not complete

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, windows-task-scheduler

I have the code below in a Module. I've tried using `Workbook_Open` in the '`ThisWorkbook`' and I've tried using `Auto_Open` in the Sheet. Neither one would run the code upon opening the spreadsheet. This is why my code is in a Module. The program runs fine if I manually open it. However, when using the task scheduler it opens the excel file and keeps running. It doesn't execute the code. The code is just a simple email with an attachment.

As for Task Scheduler, In the General tab, I have Run only when the user is logged on, and Run with the highest privileges checked.  I also have Wake the computer to run this task checked in conditions.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .to = "bjenks@ormat.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test Workbook Open"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\bjenks\Desktop\Test.xlsx")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please better describe WHEN WOULD YOU LIKE, the code in discussion, TO RUN? If you need the `Workbook_Open` event to run, please add your workbook in a trusted location (Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... - > Trusted Locations -> Add New location).

Comment: If the workbook has been downloaded, or received by mail, please go to its properties and check "Unblock" from the bottom right side and click OK.

Comment: Trust Center was the very first thing I did before even creating the task.

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked Run with the highest privileges and change to Public and it worked.

Comment: No need to make the function `Public`, anyhow.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it mattered.